# QGIS: editing vector layer with 'delete feature' option locked

Tags: qgis, vector, editing, delete, lock

I need a vector layer to be editable, to change feature geometry and attributes, but at the same time, I need to prevent users from deleting features in the layer. Is there a way of locking the 'delete feature' option for vectors (gpkg/shp) and having the edit mode on in QGIS v 3.x?

Comment: Could yo have the attributes in a linked table which is editable ?

Comment: At the file level (gpkg or shp) and according to this https://flaviocopes.com/sqlite-user-permissions/ it's not possible to restrict permission in sqlite (and so in gpkg) so it's either you give all (add, update AND delete) or nothing by setting the file in readonly. Maybe someone will come with a clever way to do that at the QGIS level...

Comment: So far the only time I've seen this possible is using PostGIS but the permissions have to be set on the database level.

Comment: Thanks this is really useful, although sadly, what I expected. 

One thing to add here is that I would like to allow users to edit the data both online and offline on mobile devices (pen computers), hence with no live access to geodatabase.
@Sethinacan - I believe, users would still be able to delete features in the linked table, don't you think?

Comment: @lukabana if you are using QField, it is possible to set up offline versions of an online project with PostGIS. have a look at https://docs.qfield.org/get-started/tutorials/advanced-setup-qfc/